# Pandas to nested json

Tags: python, pandas

My Pandas df is like:

```
RollCall    Physics Chemisty    Maths
1   20  30  25
2   25  30  30
3   15  12  35
4   20  15  30
```

I wish to convert this to a json like:

```
{"StudentDetails": {
"1":{"Physics":20,"Chemisty":30,"Maths":25},
"2":{"Physics":25,"Chemisty":30,"Maths":30},
"3":{"Physics":15,"Chemisty":12,"Maths":35},
}}
```

This is what I am doing and not getting the desired output:

```
d = {}
d['StudentDetails'] = df.to_json(orient='index')
```

Anyway to get desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case do

```
df['RollCall'] = df['RollCall'].astype(str)

d = {}
d['StudentDetails'] = df.set_index('RollCall').to_dict('index')
d
Out[366]: 
{'StudentDetails': {'1': {'Physics': 20, 'Chemisty': 30, 'Maths': 25},
  '2': {'Physics': 25, 'Chemisty': 30, 'Maths': 30},
  '3': {'Physics': 15, 'Chemisty': 12, 'Maths': 35},
  '4': {'Physics': 20, 'Chemisty': 15, 'Maths': 30}}}
```

Comment: @Anant check the update